# Use specific IPv6 address in sendmail's outgoing smtp connections

Tags: debian, sendmail, debian-stretch

I'm using sendmail on Debian 9 (version 8.15.2-8), and I'm trying to set sendmail to use a specific IPv6 address.

The system has several IPv6 addresses, but some of the do not have PTR records, which means that if sendmail uses these addresses, they don't work as well.

I would like to set sendmail to ONLY use one of the IPv6 addresses available on the system, and ignore the others. I've tried searching on Google and on stackoverflow but couldn't find anyone with a similar issue.

In `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` there are a few lines specificing which addresses to listen to:

```
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp, Addr=::')dnl
```

I of course replaced the `::` with my specific IPv6 address (and rebuilt the config and restarted sendmail), but sendmail still ends up using one of the other IPv6 addresses available on the system.

Hope I was clear enough.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `dnl` in sendmail's *.mc files marks "comment to the end of line"
2. `DAEMON_OPTIONS` are for **incoming** smtp connections.
   Use `CLIENT_OPTIONS` for **outgoing** smtp connections.

Comment: This solved it. I copied the line I used above, replaced `DAEMON_OPTIONS` with `CLIENT_OPTIONS` and added the IPv6 address. Works, thanks!

Comment: Sorry bout that, forgot it.